# How to conditionally disable a TFS field

Tags: tfs

I want to disable "State" until there is an entry in the "Original Estimate". Is it possible to disable a field based on the value of the other field?

Comment: More info: I am using TFS built in CMM template. There is no coding involved here. I think that editing an xml file should be sufficient. May be, a policy needs to written.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use witadmin.exe to download the work item that you want to edit. This will give you an XML file that you can change and upload.

You should look to the  tag.